# php foreach not working properly with explode

Tags: php, foreach, explode

Ok some php code below.

```
$user_pass = "
vortex90:OPFY4MB8
jimmy3:3M7ISWof
dave-ish-mental:YEnMMXua
cindybaby:rRHxrErp
claire-x:H4VrT8Xx
icemonster:ODId9N17
";

$token = 'token';    
$ex = explode("\r", $user_pass);

foreach ($ex as $info) {
   print "username=" . str_replace(":", "&password=", $info) . "&token=" . $token . "\n";
}
```

What i want the foreach() to do is show for each explode

```
username=username&password=password&token=token
```

But below is what gets returned.

```
vortex90&password=OPFY4MB8
jimmy3&password=3M7ISWof
dave-ish-mental&password=YEnMMXua
cindybaby&password=rRHxrErp
claire-x&password=H4VrT8Xx
icemonster&password=ODId9N17
```

Why is it not returning as expected? all answers welcome.

Comment: Possibly because you need to `explode()` on the linefeed `\n` not the carriage return `\r`.

Comment: how do you know its \r not \n or \n?

Comment: works for me as expected: http://codepad.viper-7.com/wkYlhC

Comment: you could look after the  PHP_EOL constant

Comment: Thanks it was a simple mistake i couldn't figure out

Comment: A simple `var_dump($explode)` will show you why this isn't working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me, it is better practice to use PHP_EOL:

```
$token = "bla";
$user_pass = "
vortex90:OPFY4MB8
jimmy3:3M7ISWof
dave-ish-mental:YEnMMXua
cindybaby:rRHxrErp
claire-x:H4VrT8Xx
icemonster:ODId9N17
";

$explode = explode(PHP_EOL, $user_pass);

foreach($explode as $i) {
$replace_shit  = str_replace(array("\r","\n",":"), array("","","&password="), $i);
$user_info = "username=".$replace_shit."&token=".$token."<br>\n";

echo $user_info;
}
```

DEMO: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/02f6663f7fa69c158a90fde2ab421cf52a78f7ce

Comment: FYI: `PHP_EOL` is `\n` on all platforms. Not that it matters.

Comment: Cool, I was looking at 5.3.2 in Core.php it's `define ('PHP_EOL', "\n");` for all platforms. Unless I'm reading it wrong. Still, if PHP read a Linux file saved on a Windows server, and then explode(PHP_EOL) it's contents would it then fail? Since the source file wouldn't contain `\r\n` line breaks? Windows's does not reformat text files and add missing `\r` breaks.